# Appending one stringstream to another. What's safest?

Tags: c++, stringstream

What is the difference between the following

```
stringstream a;
stringstream b;
a << "hi";
b << "there";
```

`a << " " << b.rdbuf();` or `a << " " << b.str();` or `a << " " << b.str().c_str();`

I've been using rdbuf(). I did notice that the C++ Reference says for [stringstream::rdbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/rdbuf/):

> Notice that for any successfully constructed istringstream object this
>   pointer is never NULL, even if the buffer string is empty.

I take that to mean rdbuf() will not return NULL? I can't pass NULL. I've had faults like this `char *array = NULL; a << array;`. If the stringstream b is empty then is the behavior defined when doing `a << b.rdbuf() << "some text"`? Wouldn't in that case the first character returned by rdbuf have eof traits, and therefore nothing in b would be appended?

Thanks

Comment: *Aside*: cplusplus.com is not "**the** C++ Reference", it is "**a** C++ reference." For correctness, many people prefer http://cppreference.com. Of course, **the** reference is the ISO C++ standard, in either the 2003 or 2011 version.

Comment: what about the obvious `a << " " << b;` ?

Comment: @moooeeeep You can't append stringstreams that way.

Comment: Of course, just checked if it compiles, not whether it produces the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference ?

They are all equivalent in effect, but they may differ in performance or efficiency.

> I take that to mean rdbuf() will not return NULL?

You take it correctly.

> If the stringstream b is empty then is the behavior defined?

Yes.

> Wouldn't in that case the first character returned by rdbuf have eof traits?

No. The first call to `.sgetc()` (or `.snextc()`) would not return a character with eof traits, it would return EOF (which *is not a character*). So, your example would be equivalent to `a << "" << "some text"`.